# Solving key error of a python notebook after importation

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, keyerror

Good day everyone. I tried importing a notebook `configs.ipynb` to another notebook `app.ipynb`. However, after importation, I got an error which is a key error. The error is below:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-789a3306b22a> in <module>()
      1 import import_ipynb
----> 2 import configs

8 frames
configs.ipynb in <module>()

<decorator-gen-91> in cd(self, parameter_s)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/magics/osm.py in cd(self, parameter_s)
    355             else:
    356                 cwd = py3compat.getcwd()
--> 357                 dhist = self.shell.user_ns['_dh']
    358                 if oldcwd != cwd:
    359                     dhist.append(cwd)

KeyError: '_dh'
```

This is the file in the `configs.ipynb` below:

```
from attrdict import AttrDict  # type: ignore

config = {
    "encoder_path": "/content/drive/MyDrive/decoder_model.bin",
    "decoder_path": "/content/drive/MyDrive/encoder_model.bin",
    "input_word_index": "/content/drive/MyDrive/input_word_index.pkl",
    "target_word_index": "/content/drive/MyDrive/target_word_index.pkl",
    "url": "https://api.mymemory.translated.net/get",
    "max_length_src": 47,
    "max_length_tar": 47,
}
config = AttrDict(config)
```

Please help me solve the error. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the concept. Please correct me if I'm wrong. You're trying to import the `configs` function written in the `configs.ipynb` to another notebook right ?

If you're doing this then you may need to copy and paste below python `configs` function to `configs.py` in the same folder where you have the another notebook `app.ipynb`.

Please copy below function to `configs.py` file.

```py
from attrdict import AttrDict  # type: ignore

config = {
    "encoder_path": "/content/drive/MyDrive/decoder_model.bin",
    "decoder_path": "/content/drive/MyDrive/encoder_model.bin",
    "input_word_index": "/content/drive/MyDrive/input_word_index.pkl",
    "target_word_index": "/content/drive/MyDrive/target_word_index.pkl",
    "url": "https://api.mymemory.translated.net/get",
    "max_length_src": 47,
    "max_length_tar": 47,
}
config = AttrDict(config)
```

Now you file structure would be like this:

```sh
Main Folder
├── configs.py # Make sure you have this.
├── configs.ipynb
├── app.ipynb
```

then go to the `app.ipynb` and do the following

```py
import configs
```

Comment: I did put them into a folder called notebooks, prior to the time I asked this question, it gave me error

Comment: You can not import notebooks directly. You need to convert it to `python function` and then do `import`.

Comment: thank you for your response sir. Please tell me how to do it sir

Comment: Please post the error ! It worked perfectly fine on my machine, I had also updated the file structure in the answer.

Comment: Mr Jay. Thank you very much. My mistake was that I used the notebook not the script for the import

Answer (score 0):

The marked answer does not take into consideration if you do not want to convert notebooks to python files.

If you would like to import a notebook to another or import a function from a notebook to another then there are multiple ways.

1. `ipynb` module

   > pip install ipynb --upgrade

   > from ipynb.fs.full.<base_file> import
2. `importlib` module

   > import sys, importlib

   > importlib.reload(sys.modules['file_name'])

   > from file_name import *